# Plataforma de criação de cursos online Python e Django

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django, python-requests

Estou montando uma plataforma de criação de cursos online, e estou usando Python e Django. Gostaria de saber se já existem bibliotecas de Django com esse intuito. Um exemplo que estou usando é a biblioteca Taggit que existe para auxiliar na criação de fóruns.

Basicamente o que preciso fazer é uma serie de requests, onde um professor pode criar conteúdo, esse conteúdo ser enviado para o administrador da plataforma que deve aprovar ou não.

Acredito que o DJango já possua alguma do tipo e estou comendo mosca.

Answer (score -2):

O que você está criando é uma plataforma de gestão de conteúdo (Content Management System - CMS).

Eu conheço essas aplicações Open Source e gratuitas feitas em Python/Django

- Django CMS - https://www.django-cms.org/en/
- Mezzanine - http://mezzanine.jupo.org/
- WagTail - https://wagtail.io/
- FeinCMS - http://www.feincms.org/
- Ella - http://ella.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- Django-page-cms - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-page-cms/

Uma dessas ai vai resolver o teu problema.